# Counting items over time using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Given a list of items with start and end dates (Nobel Physics prize winners with birth and death in Wikidata, for example), how could I use SPARQL to return a count of the number in existence in every year of a certain range? For example, how many Nobel winners were alive every year from 1950 to 2000?

I can see how to count the winners alive in a single year, such as 1950:

```
SELECT (COUNT (DISTINCT ?nobel) AS ?count)
WHERE 
{
  ?nobel wdt:P166 wd:Q38104.
  ?nobel wdt:P569 ?birthdate
  OPTIONAL{?nobel wdt:P570 ?deathdate.}
  FILTER(YEAR(?birthdate) <= 1950 && YEAR(?deathdate) >= 1950)
}
```

But is there a way to get the count for *every* year between 1950 and 2000?

(I realize that I could get a table of birth and death dates for every winner and get my answer in another program, but I wonder if I could do it using only SPARQL.)

Comment: Like this: https://w.wiki/6EKF

Comment: Amazing @StanislavKralin --thanks! I think I understand. Lines 2 and 3 create a list of integers corresponding to the years I seek, and that list makes a filter for the "real" search that follows. 

I have a followup question: are there other ways to produce a list of integers? I ask because I'm working with my own wikibase, outside wikidata. I'm trying to use wikidata as a service--can't see what isn't working with this query: https://ottgaz.org/wiki/Querying#How_many_kazas_between_1800_and_1900?.

Comment: Why isn't there a period at the end of line ?

Comment: Sorry--I meant at the end of line 2...